(org-mode) How can I put a newline between bibliography entries?
This problem has been driving me mad for a couple days now. The basic problem: I would like bibliography entries to be separated by a blank line, rather than right next to each other. Currently I am running Doom Emacs along with whatever tools that supplies for org-cite etc. I am an Emacs newbie, so I apologize if I do not know all the details.
I solved a similar issue to this recently, namely to have a blank space between footnotes. To accomplish this, I simply inserted #+latex_header: \setlength\footnotesep{\baselineskip} Near the top of my org doc. This worked fine, and made total sense to me, since I have used LaTeX a good bit before coming to Emacs. Naturally, I figured I could use the same solution for the bibliography and so inserted #+latex_header: \setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip} just below it. Altogether, my header looked like this:
#+title: Test LaTeX Article
#+filetags: :article:
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+latex_header: \usepackage[backend=biber, doi=false,isbn=false,eprint=false]{biblatex-chicago}
#+latex_header: \setlength\footnotesep{\baselineskip}
#+latex_header: \setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
#+latex: \clearpage
#+HEADERS: :results: value latex

However, this had no effect on my bibliography.

I then figured there may be some disconnect between how org-mode handles bibliographies and how LaTeX handles them. I had been using #+print_bibliography: so far, and so I decided to try out #+latex: \printbibliography instead. This returned nothing.

So I figured perhaps I needed to specify my bibliography location in LaTeX code at the top (even though I already have the global location for my bibliography stored in my config), but that also did nothing.
Here is how the exported LaTeX code looked like with #+print_bibliography:, if it's any help:
\begin{document}

...

\section{Bibliography}
\label{sec:org4eb06fa}
\begin{hangparas}{1.5em}{1}
Camus, Albert. \textit{The Stranger}. Translated by Matthew Ward. New York, New York: Vintage Books, 1989.

Ellul, Jacques. \textit{Anarchy and Christianity}. Translated by Geoffrey W. Brimiley. Grand Rapids, MI: William B. Eerdmans Publishing Co., 1991.

Hegel, G. W. F. \textit{The Phenomenology of Spirit}. Translated by Peter Fuss and John Dobbins. Notre Dame, Indiana: University of Notre Dame Press, 2019.

Ngo, Richard.  Towards More Cooperative AI Safety Strategies,  July 2024.

Wiles, Will.  The Behavioral Sink.  \textit{Cabinet}, no. 42 (2011).\bigskip
\end{hangparas}
\end{document}

I would greatly appreciate if someone would help me understand what is happening, and/or point me in the direction of some resources to more fully understand how org interfaces with LaTeX. Again, I am an Emacs newbie, and while I have used LaTeX before, I am not really that knowledgeable about it either, so there is a large possibility I am missing something obvious. Thanks in advance!

You seem to be using a non-LaTeX org citation processor, csl or basic. If you want to fine-tune the LaTeX output then it might be better to switch to one of the LaTeX-based ones: bibtex, natbib or biblatex. If you want to use the csl processor then there other solutions: the latest Org version (you seem to be using an earlier one) honors the line spacing settings of the used csl style, so you can edit the style and change this setting, or customize the variable org-cite-csl-latex-preamble, which contains the definitions of the LaTeX commands used for bibliography formatting.

Thank you @Simka, that is immensely helpful. For some reason I thought that csl's simply told biblatex how to interpret a .bib entry, not that they were an entirely separate thing. This does present the new problem of how to have Chicago formatting using just biblatex... I will look into the issue and hopefully be able to answer my own question.

Okay, so thanks to @Simka, I figured out that part of the problem was that I was using csl as my org citation processor rather than biblatex. So then I tried using (setq org-cite-export-processors '((latex biblatex) (t csl))) in my config to use biblatex with csl as a fallback. Then, I downloaded biblatex-chicago to format the biblatex entries according to the Chicago MoS. This isn't exactly relevant to this specific question, but it is part of my larger goal, and might affect other parts of my answer, so I'm including it here. After this, everything seemed to work! ... except that I got tons of "undefined reference" errors. But at least the spacing was right.
I did eventually fix my issue. However, I don't really know why it works, since I tried this exact solution about 30m ago and it didn't work. Now, after trying some different things, I went back to my initial solution to check the error logs, but it just worked. The first approach I rigorously tried out was to use xelatex for org-latex-pdf-process, like so:
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "biber --output-directory %o $(basename %f .tex)"
        "xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))

Like I said, this did not work at first, so I fiddled around with latexmk as an alternative. I did a lot of things in between, mostly just throwing spaghetti at the wall, so I don't know what exactly caused xelatex to start working.
Overall, the solution, as far as I can tell, is:

Set your org-cite-processors to biblatex thus: (setq org-cite-export-processors '((latex biblatex) (t csl)))
Ensure org-latex-pdf-process is working. In my case, fiddle around with variants of: (setq org-latex-pdf-process '("xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f" ... etc. as shown above.
Insert #+latex_header: \setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip} at the top of your org file.

Note that if you also use #+latex_header: \usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}, that last step is more or less irrelevant since biblatex-chicago already formats the bibliography entries with a space between them.
Unfortunately I have had further issues, but they seem to be unrelated to how to add a space in between bibliography entries so I will leave them off for now.

You'll always get undefined references the first time you latex a file: once you do the biber processing, you need to latex a second time and the undefined references should go away. So your original, four-stage org-pdf-process should work.

The issue is that no matter how many times I run org-latex-export-to-pdf, it returns the same undefined citation errors. Is there a different command/series of commands I should be running in Emacs? Moreover, is there a way to streamline the process so I only have to run one macro command?

I have a question posted for this issue here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/82067/minimal-org-file-yields-undefined-citation-when-exporting-to-latex-using-bibla

I said "...you need to latex a second time and the undefined references should go away": that is wrong - it will need at least one more run after that. See the EDIT in the answer to the question you linked to above.
