Minimal org file yields [undefined citation] when exporting to LaTeX using biblatex
I have looked for similar questions, but none of the solutions have worked for me, and they seem to be slightly different in nature. I am just trying to get citations to work with biblatex-chicago, but nothing seems to work. I got it to work temporarily in this thread, but then, as I pointed out in a later thread, this immediately broke when I changed the file's name.
This issue is as stated in the title. I have a very minimal org file with a single reference, and biblatex fails to find the citation. The .bib file is in the same directory as the org file. Here is the org file:
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       b7703f67-46ac-45ac-94f6-53f4bae72be4
:END:
#+title: Test Minimal Article
#+filetags: :article:
#+bibliography: references.bib
#+latex_header: \usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
#+options: toc:nil

* Lorem
Ipsum dolor sit amet.[cite:@hoellerGnosticismNewLight2002]

#+print_bibliography:

Here are relevant sections from my config:
(setq org-cite-export-processors '((latex biblatex) (t csl)))
(setq org-cite-csl-styles-dir "~/texm/tex/latex/styles-master")

(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "biber --output-directory %o $(basename %f .tex)"
        "xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))


And also the .bib entry:
@book{hoellerGnosticismNewLight2002,
  title = {Gnosticism : New Light on the Ancient Tradition of Inner Knowing},
  shorttitle = {Gnosticism},
  author = {Hoeller, Stephan A.},
  year = {2002},
  publisher = {Quest Books},
  address = {Wheaton, Illinois},
  abstract = {xi, 257 p. : 23 cm; Includes bibliographical references (p. 241-243) and index},
  collaborator = {{Internet Archive}},
  langid = {english},
  keywords = {Gnosticism,THE402}
}

If anyone could help me figure out what is going on, I would greatly appreciate it.
EDIT: Requested error messages from Emacs/LaTeX:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(../Test Minimal Article.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-06-05>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/capt-of/capt-of.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/biblatex-chicago.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/chicago-notes.bbx)
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/chicago-notes.cbx)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))))
(/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export//Test Minimal Article.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export//Test Minimal Article.out)
(/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export//Test Minimal Article.out)
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/cms-american.lbx
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
No file "Test Minimal Article".bbl.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hoellerGnosticismNewLight2002' on page 1 undefined on 
input line 35.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 37.

[1] (/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export/Test Minimal Article.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                "Test Minimal Article"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
Output written on /home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export/Test Minimal Article.pdf (1 p
age).
Transcript written on /home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export//Test Minimal Article.log
.
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(../Test Minimal Article.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-06-05>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/capt-of/capt-of.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/biblatex-chicago.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/chicago-notes.bbx)
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/chicago-notes.cbx)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))))
(/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export//Test Minimal Article.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export//Test Minimal Article.out)
(/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export//Test Minimal Article.out)
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/cms-american.lbx
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
No file "Test Minimal Article".bbl.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hoellerGnosticismNewLight2002' on page 1 undefined on 
input line 35.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 37.

[1] (/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export/Test Minimal Article.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                "Test Minimal Article"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
Output written on /home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export/Test Minimal Article.pdf (1 p
age).
Transcript written on /home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export//Test Minimal Article.log
.
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is '/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export/Test.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'Test.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(../Test Minimal Article.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-06-05>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/capt-of/capt-of.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/biblatex-chicago.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/chicago-notes.bbx)
(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/chicago-notes.cbx)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))))
No file "Test Minimal Article".aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

(/home/vegash/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/latex/cms-american.lbx
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
No file "Test Minimal Article".bbl.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hoellerGnosticismNewLight2002' on page 1 undefined on 
input line 35.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 37.

[1] (/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export/Test Minimal Article.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                "Test Minimal Article"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
Output written on /home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export/Test Minimal Article.pdf (1 p
age).
Transcript written on /home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export//Test Minimal Article.log
.

EDIT2: More errors after doing suggested replacement of biber line as per @NickD: https://pastebin.com/2bQuNFcL and https://pastebin.com/zJB22aCc

I started with emacs -Q (and tried both 29.4 and a fairly recent upstream 31.0.50), ran  a code block containing the initialization you show, and exported to PDF: it all works fine for me. Can you post the complete error message(s) you get?

As I point out in a comment in the linked question, citation handling in LaTeX is a multi-stage process: starting with just the .tex file, you'll always get undefined references the first time you latex. It is only after the biber/bibtex step that that .bbl file is produced, so a subsequent latex will see that all the references are defined. The four-stage org-pdf-latex-process you show should DTRT.

Okay, thank you. I will append the error messages to the post. I have been using C-c C-e l p to generate PDFs. No matter how many times I run that command, I get PDF file produced with warnings: [undefined citation]. How can I do the proper steps to produce the PDF within Emacs? If not possible, I suppose I could figure out the steps outside of Emacs and then make an elisp script to take care of them. I am pretty new to both LaTeX and Emacs.

I do have biber installed. I made sure earlier today.

Yup, sorry I missed it in the log.

The log says: INFO - This is Biber 2.19 INFO - Logfile is '/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export/Test.blg' ERROR - Cannot find 'Test.bcf'!  INFO - ERRORS: 1. Try running the commands by hand in a terminal: first xelatex and see if there is a Test.bcf file produced, then biber on that file.

Somebody gets confused with the spaces in the file name: try a file name without spaces.

Running xelatex manually produces a .bcf file. I tested again in emacs using org-latex-export-to-pdf and no .bcf file was created.

It seems the biber command line mangles the spaces in the file name: try replacing the biber string in org-latex-pdf-process with this: "biber --output-directory \"%o\" \"$(basename \"%f\" .tex)\"" - not sure that all the quoting is necessary, but it seems to work for me. It's probably the case that basename is mishandling the spaces.

Only the $(basename ...) needs to be explicitly quoted - see answer.

The problem is caused by the spaces in the filename: the biber command line mishandles those, because $(basename "/some/path/foo bar.tex" .tex) returns foo bar with an exposed (not-quoted) space. So the biber command needs to be modified to this string in org-latex-pdf-process:
    ...
    "biber --output-directory %o \"$(basename %f .tex)\""
    ...

explicitly quoting the returned value of the basename call. %f  and %o are internally quoted, so they don't cause problems on their own.]

EDIT: summarize and expand the discussion in the comments
As Lamport points out on p.66 of the LaTeX book, whenever LaTeX has to move information around --- tables of contents (or figures and other floats), page references, bibliographic citations, making an index or a glossary ---, it uses information stored in files that are produced in the previous run of LaTeX. So in order to have all that information be completely up to date, you may need to run LaTeX multiple times, and you may need to run additional programs in-between those runs. E.g. to produce bibliographic citations, LaTeX uses a .bbl file which is usually produced by bibtex or biber. In turn, these programs get their information from a file that is produced by the previous run of LaTeX: see Lamport, p. 207 for the files that are produced (note that the .bcf file that biber uses is not listed there: the book predates the invention of biber); also see Lamport, p.71 for the description of the process and for the reason that both the first and the second run of LaTeX (with the biber run in-between) produce Undefined reference warnings.
As long as you don't add or change citations, the .bbl file that was produced during the last run of biber or bibtex is still good. You will still get other warnings because labels and page numbers may need updating, but the reference list stays constant.
In light of all this, it is best not to worry about such warnings while you are writing (remember, LaTeX was meant to help write books and articles that are rarely, if ever, done in one sitting: they are revised again and again, constantly adding citations and perhaps changing or removing some). During the final pass before publication, you do the full sequence of runs needed until a run of LaTeX does not report any undefined references (or other warnings) any more.
Of course, errors (as opposed to warnings) are another matter: you got to fix those as you go. As noted in the comments below the question, the *Org PDF LaTeX output* buffer is indispensable in figuring out what is wrong.

After doing as you said, I reran the command and still got errors. I even created a copy of the file called testmin.org and the errors persisted. Pastebins in post edit 2.

The error in the second pastebin is now ERROR - Cannot find '/home/vegash/is/notes/zk/export/org files/references.bib'! - please check that it exists. You might also try cleaning up everything except the Org mode file and the .bib file and starting afresh.

And make sure that you re-evaluate the (setq org-latex-pdf-process ...) after you change the biber string. Just editing the string is not enough: you'll need to say C-x C-e after the closing paren in the above expression or restart your emacs, so that the new definition gets evaluated.

Yes, I fixed that issue, and now the one without spaces generates just fine. I initially had some issues with the spaced file names, but eventually I sorted that out too by removing an error in my config. Thanks so much! Now, is there any way to do the org-latex-export-to-pdf twice as a convenience?

I don't understand: why do you want to do it twice?

I have to run the command twice. The first time always produces [undefined citation]

But the PDF file is correct, right? Both the citation and the bibliography should be correct.If that's the case, I would suggest that you don't worry about the warning: if you start from scratch, you will always get a warning: at least one from the first xelatex run and possibly again from the second one (although I'm not sure why that is). There should generally be no warning from the last run - but no guarantees. See p.66 of the LaTeX book (2nd ed.) for explanations: he mentions that it's possible to have a pathological case, where the cross-ref info is never correct, but it's very rare.

My org-latex-pdf-process is a single call of latexmk: it does one run of xelatex, then a run of biber, then three more runs of xelatex (there is a warning after the first one of these three, but not after the second (just as above with the explicit setting of org-latex-pdf-process), so I presume the last xelatex run is just making double sure that the cross-refs have all stabilized. Here's my setting if interested: ("latexmk --shell-escape -pdf -xelatex -output-directory=%o %f") - the --shell-escape is needed because I use minted but you might not need it.
